# Hold together a background image and a text over it while zooming

Tags: html, image, css

This is my navbar, composed by some links over a background image. I've positioned the image using:

```
background-position: x% y%;
```

When I resize or zoom the page, the position of the image and links change. Because of this, the links goes onto the vegetation in the photo, and the contrast make them unreadable. So, is there a way to group or hold the links and the image together, in order to keep them in the position that I declare with `background-position: x% y%;` when I'm at 100% of zoom?

[image]

Comment: Tried using pixels instead of percentages?

Comment: @j08691 Yes---maybe a bit better, but definitely not usable.

Comment: have you set the background-size: 100%?

Comment: @Chausser yes but look at this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdDio

Answer (score 1):

I would figure out where the vegetation starts on the left, looks roughly 10%.  Then have something like this:

```
.background {
  background-position: left center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
.text-wrapper { /*Some wrapper around the header and links, alternatively you could use something like h1, a:first-child */
  margin-left: 10%; /* the value of this being the % that the vegetation starts */
}
```

Comment: @FormlessCloud I added some code to the code pen - some of it was to make it look like the original question, the rest to update the css.  CSS wise, that's about the best you can do, anything more and you'll have to use javascript.  Its responsive down to about 600px wide